# Create new data frames in a loop

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I got an original dataframe **df** with three columns:

"Person","start","end", where **start** and ***end*** are in "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S" format.

```
head(df)

1 Mark 06.08.2019 00:02:56 06.08.2019 00:14:43
5 Mark 06.08.2019 00:16:31 06.08.2019 00:20:53
6 Vince 06.08.2019 00:18:28 06.08.2019 00:24:30
7   Kate 06.08.2019 00:20:26 06.08.2019 00:23:29
8   Mark 06.08.2019 00:26:34 06.08.2019 00:32:41
9 Vince 06.08.2019 00:31:13 06.08.2019 00:33:14
```

Person has unique values:

```
people<-unique(df$Person)

people=[Mark,Kate, Vince]
```

So my goal is to make 3 separated dataframes for those people.
Im trying this:

```
for (a in people){
  assign(paste("df.", a, sep = ""), subset(a,a[start],a[end]))
}
```

since **start** and **end** are atomic vectors

```
(is.atomic(...))
```

but I receive an error saying:

```
Error in subset.default(a,a[start],a[end]) : 
  object 'start' not found
```

I wonder how to have separated **df**s for every person with the same columns as in original DF dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split your original dataframe into a list of dataframes:

```
df_split <- split(df,f= df$Person)
```

You can then access each dataframe by using for example `df[["Mark"]]`. Does that work for you?